# Configure task cards on agile board in Youtrack to show more than 2 custom fields?

Tags: agile, youtrack

How to configure cards in youtrack agile board to show more than 2 custom fields at the bottom line?

I want something like this:

[image: Agile board card]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not unfortunately possible at the moment.
As a workaround, you can switch to Edit issue mode on the board, by either double clicking the card or with F2 key.